# what are the licenses and how is stellar validate an anchor?

Tags: anchor

I found every information about technical parts of being an anchor, but I couldn't find anything about certificates or licenses needed by stellar. We are a startup and we have all the requirement in the technical side, but we don't know where to start and what kind of license we must looking for to be accepted by the stellar.I would be happy if anyone from stellar or anybody with experience could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stellar is a public, open-participation network.  That means you can start building on it today, no permission required.  You don't need a license to use the network.

However, if you want to anchor a currency — which means that you connect Stellar to existing financial infrastructure by accepting deposits using legacy rails and crediting Stellar accounts with the digital equivalent and, on the flip side, redeeming Stellar-network assets for the underlying assets they represent — you need to comply with local laws and regulations, and that means you need to obtain the proper licenses for you business.

There are different kinds of licenses for different kinds of [money service businesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_services_business), and they vary from region to region.  So your best bet is to talk to someone in your region (probably a lawyer) who can help you understand the local laws and regulations, and get their advice about which licenses you need and how to apply for them.